# Gzip: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gzip, archive

folks. I've just wrong `gzip` my `/etc/` folder on Ubuntu 10.10 (It's my home Internet server). So, the wrong command to gzip have changed the original files in `/etc/` folder with .gz ones. 
The server doesn't start now. 
Then I've booted from disk with Ubuntu live and tried to extract files in /etc/:
`gunzip -r *.* /etc/` 

But I've got a problem for some files: 
`file.gz too many levels of symbolic links` 
Any suggestions? (I need to extract all the files with the replacing to restore my system)

Comment: you mean to say you by accident **gziped /etc**?

Comment: I says...  "oops"!  :-D  That's almost as good as witching my sysadmin type `rm -rf /tmp/.*` and then wonder why it was taking so long...

Comment: Sounds like a symlink loop (or simply pointing to itself).

Comment: I would love to see the answer for this question. I did exactly the same thing and now my server is still in coma :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the manual pages for gzip (*man gzip*), or read the output of this command:

```
gzip --help | less
```

Perhaps, you should try

```
 gzip -d --force * /etc
```

I hope that this helps you.